# Can't connect MassTransit to Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, masstransit

I did everything according to this [example](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox/blob/master/src/Sample.Components/RegistrationDbContext.cs). However, I keep getting the error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "InboxState" does not exist

Comment: Did the migration actually execute?

Comment: Seems like the database migration wasn't applied to the database, that isn't an MassTransit concern, that's on you.